# how to user prefetch_related and select_related in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I have something like this in Model

```
class Task(model.Models):
    name=model.CharField(max=100)
    
class attachments(model.Models):
    file=model.FileField()
    task=model.Foreginkey(Task)
```

**In views**

```
class myView(APIView):
  task=Task.object.get(id=1)
  task_serilizer=TaskSerilizer(task, many=False)
```

**in Serilizer**

```
class Myserilizer(aerilizer.Serilizers):
    class Meta:
       fields='__all__'
```

Now I want to know how I can user select related and prefetch related , its quite confusing right now (And I wrote this code using mobile so kindly forgive me about this)

Comment: `task=Task.object.prefetch_related('attachment_set').get(id=1)`? But since this is a single object, it does not make any difference performance-wise.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  how to  use this in serialize ?  like how I can come to know in serilizer that I have now attachments

Comment: and sir @WillemVanOnsem  someone said to me I need to do write  setup_eager_loading()  in serilizers ? I am completely lost

Comment: use in `get_queryset()`

Comment: @CharanjitSingh  then how to use these in Serilizer ?

Comment: sir @WillemVanOnsem I need help :(

Comment: In Serializer you can access the object using `source = 'related_field.field_name;` in serializer field or from serializermethodField, you get `obj` from where you can get the related field.